# How can i fix cors error in react and laravel project

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am sending a request from my react app localhost:8080 to my lumen api localhost:8000 to retrieve json data.

This is my routes.php in lumen: $app->get('list', 'ArticleController@listAll');

Comment: Have you added in a CORS middleware on your laravel project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to install `fruitcake/laravel-cors` library and follow the instructions to create a middleware and such